# Can an optimization problem be both linear and quadratic programming concurrently?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming

I only know of **linear programming (LP)** optimization by itself, and **quadratic programming (QP)** optimization by itself, but I have never seen them mixed within the same objective function. For example, a model that concurrently solves an **outer maximization** problem as well as an **inner minimization** one.

Say I have a "bigger picture" model that must be solved with linear programming as an outer maximization, which at the same time requires an inner minimization model to derive an optimal decision variable using quadratic programming.

Am I allowed to mix LP with QP like this in the same objective function? Could you give examples of actual models from any field that mix LP with QP? I want to know what the objective function looks like and how the notation is done

(To avoid only receiving min-max or minimax as an answer, the example I mentioned could even be outer *and* inner maximization.)

Comment: QP encompasses LP, so every LP is a QP. The tractability of mixed models depends on how the models interact. Do you have an example in mind of a "bigger picture" model?

Comment: @LinAlg the bigger picture model is the **optimal transport** which is solved with LP, while the inner minimization model to embed in it is **portfolio weight optimization** which minimizes portfolio variance with QP. Optimal transport (LP) takes a source distribution/histogram $\alpha$ and minimizes the cost of transferring its mass to a target distribution/histogram $\beta$. I would like to use the portfolio weighted return distribution from the QP model and embed it as the *source* distribution $\alpha$ in the LP problem

Comment: Can't you just solve the problems sequentially? How does the transport problem affect which portfolio you select?

Comment: I guess it's more of a want to solve both problems concurrently rather than sequentially. The transport problem is affected by the fact that different combinations of portfolio weights from the QP model would result in a different source distribution of portfolio returns being input into the LP model

Comment: Just to clarify, different combinations of portfolio weights are all optimal to the inner problem? It sounds like an easy problem to solve concurrently because the only interaction is through the right hand side of the LP.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "right hand side of the LP", but i know what you're trying to say that the optimal minimum of the inner portfolio problem is a unique, deterministic outcome. I guess it's not as important to me to have a definitive source portfolio distribution to construct, but to combinatorially calculate a portfolio return source distribution that comes *closest to* the target distribution specified in the LP transport model. Therefore, I only mentioned the minimum variance portfolio to you as a well-known example, but in fact, it doesn't have to be that portfolio specifically

Comment: Could you post your full problem? What I mean is that if you put the LP in standard form ($\min\{c^Tx : Ax=b, x\geq 0\}$), that the portfolio solution only affects $b$.

Answer (score 2):

You seen to be referring to what is called Bilevel Optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization .

If your inner problem is a QP, you would include the KKT conditions for the QP as additional constraints to the outer problem. This overall problem would no longer be an LP due to the complementarity constraints in the KKT conditions, and is called a
Mathematical Program with Equilibrium Constraints (MPEC) https://neos-guide.org/content/mathematical-programs-equilibrium-constraints or Mathematical Program with Complementarity Constraints (MPCC).

Comment: could you fix the second link, it doesn't work

Comment: The link was working. The website https://neos-guide.org is down now. Hopefully it will come back up soon.

Comment: let me know when it's back

Comment: https://neos-guide.org/content/mathematical-programs-equilibrium-constraints is now working again.

Comment: Is **bi-level optimization** the same as **multi-level programming**. both terms are not very popular in search. could you recommend a good textbook

Comment: For bilevel programming, you can read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.06270.pdf .Googling       bilevel programming book    brings up some books,.  Bilevel Programming (optimization) is the special case of Mult-level Programing with 2 levels. There are youtube videos on bilevel programming at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTDrSjBtKLc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGRwG4j8AGA .